# Redshift COPY not parsing date correctly, but INSERT works

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I have a table in AWS Redshift with `TIMESTAMP` column. When I try to `INSERT` the value like `2/1/2022 12:00:00 AM`, it works well. When I try to `COPY` it, the value is `2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 +00:00`, so the date part works ok, but the hour is always zero.

To reproduce, the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE store_sales (
  "datetime" TIMESTAMP,
  "store" VARCHAR(32),
  "count" INTEGER,
  "value" INTEGER
);
```

Example CSV file that I'm copying data from:

```
date,store,count,value
2/1/2022 12:00:00 AM,Store 1,4,2
2/1/2022 12:00:00 AM,Test Store,2-,3
2/1/2022 12:00:00 AM,MyStore,3,5
```

My `COPY` options (I'm using Python and Apache Airflow for running the actual SQL to copy from S3 to Redshift):

```
copy_options = [
    "REGION 'eu-central-1'",
    "CSV",
    "DELIMITER ','",
    "IGNOREHEADER 1",
    "TIMEFORMAT AS 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'",
    "TRIMBLANKS",
]
```

The important bit is probably the `TIMEFORMAT`. I tried using `'auto'`, but it gave the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12:00:00 AM is the same as 00:00:00 in a timestamp, so if your hour is coming back as zero, that's expected. If your time was 12:00:00 PM, that would be 12:00:00 on a 24hr timestamp.

Looks like everything's working as expected here. If you disagree, please add more info to the question.

Comment: I use 24h clock regularly, so I totally missed this. Thank you!